# How to attach metadata to each frame of a video

Tags: video, metadata, file-format

I would like to be able to store metadata on each frame of a video file (a key to value map with ~10 entries per frame).

Which video format allows me to store such data ?

Where can I find a c++ library to do this ?

Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid idea:
Could you write your meta data in a separate text file? You could write for every timestamp one line and add your key-value pairs

Answer (score -1):

[FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) does such thing.

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -metadata title="my title" out.flv
```

So if you want a library to do this, you can take a look at libavcodec (the leading audio/video codec library).

Comment: This will add metadata to the video file but not for every frame as I am asking for.

Obviously, every frame should be able to store different values for the same keys.

Comment: Well, the command-line posted above is just a simple example. Libavcodec will allow you to do what you're looking for.

Comment: Maybe this can get you started: line 1413 of --> http://www.dennedy.org/kinodox/frame_8cc-source.html

Comment: It is a simple example, yes -- to the point of not answering OP's question. 

Comment: @Jameson Thx for the comment. Great post on leaving Amazon, btw.